# Why pathMatch gives "Invalid configuration of route" error?

Tags: angular, angular-router

This is the error message I get:

```
Error: Invalid configuration of route '{path: "teams/", redirectTo: "all"}': please provide 'pathMatch'. The default value of 'pathMatch' is 'prefix', but often the intent is to use 'full'.
```

Here is my syntax in `app.module.ts`:

```
 const routes = [
     { path: 'teams', component: TabsComponent, children: [
         { path: '', redirectTo: 'all', pathMatch: 'full' },
         { path: ':side', component: ListComponent }
     ] },
     { path: 'new-team', component: CreateTeamComponent },
     { path: '**', redirectTo: '/teams' }
];
```

Why do I still have the error?

Comment: You have a typo in pathMatch.

Answer (score 24):

By default, Angular matches paths by prefix. That means, that the following route will match both /recipes  and just /

`{ path: '', redirectTo: '/somewhere-else' }`

Actually, Angular will give you an error here, because that's a common gotcha: This route will now ALWAYS redirect you! Why?

Since the default matching strategy is "prefix" , Angular checks if the path you entered in the URL does start with the path specified in the route. Of course every path starts with ''  (Important: That's no whitespace, it's simply "nothing").

To fix this behavior, you need to change the matching strategy to "full" :

`{ path: '', redirectTo: '/somewhere-else', pathMatch: 'full' }`

Now, you only get redirected, if the full path is ''  (so only if you got NO other content in your path in this example).

Answer (score 4):

A redirect route requires a `pathMatch` property to tell the router how to match a URL to the path of a route. The router throws an error if you don't.

From angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#redirecting-routes)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code:

```
const routes = [
 {
    path: 'teams', component: TabsComponent, children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'all', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: ':side', component: ListComponent }
    ]
 },
 { path: 'new-team', component: CreateTeamComponent },
 { path: '**', redirectTo: '/teams' }
];
```

You have a typo, you are writing **pathMacth** instead of **pathMatch**

Answer (score 1):

#### For some beginners like me, here is my summary for this case.

- `pathMatch = 'prefix'`. Route’s path is the prefix of what is left in the URL.
- `pathMatch = 'full'`. The path is “equal” to what is left in the URL